# Selenium tests error in Firefox when setting Host property to ::1 (geckodriver)

Tags: performance, selenium, firefox, driver, geckodriver

I am trying to set Firefox to use IPv6 as opposed to the default IPv4 because it runs extremely slowly compared with Chrome.
I have followed the instructions on the following threads:

[Firefox Webdriver is extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078586/firefox-webdriver-is-extremely-slow)

[Selenium geckodriver executes findElement 10 times slower than chromedriver (.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629542/selenium-geckodriver-executes-findelement-10-times-slower-than-chromedriver-ne)

My code looks like this:

```
                FirefoxOptions firefox = new FirefoxOptions();
                FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                service.Host = "::1";
                firefox.AddArgument("-headless");
                return new FirefoxDriver(service, firefox);
```

I have also tried passing in the geckodriver location like this:

```
                FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(LocalConfig.Root + "bin\\Debug", "geckodriver.exe");
```

The error I get is the following:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service
> on http://localhost:50171/

If I set service.Host to be an empty string, the tests will run without any errors.

If I pass it a load of random characters, it'll produce the same error as above, leading me to wonder if it even recognises the ::1 string.

Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a new bug. It's being looked at in the following places if anyone else is experiencing the same problem:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1732622

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1936

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1935